# Populating UICollectionView from Online Database

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios-lifecycle

I'm creating a simple chat app, it has a loading screen with a segue to either the login screen if the user is not logged in or directly to his chats if he is. The chats are displayed in a `UICollectionView`. When I was first testing, I populated it with dummy data which I declared in the class itself, and everything worked fine. Now I am fetching the user's chats from an online database in the Loading Screen, and storing them in an array called `user_chats` which is declared globally.

[image]

I use the following code to populate the `UICollectionView` :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   // getUserChats()
    return user_chats.count

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("chat_cell" , forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SingleChat

cell.chatName?.text = user_chats[indexPath.row].chat_partner!.name
cell.chatTextPreview?.text = user_chats[indexPath.row].chat_messages!.last!.text
let profile_pic_URL = NSURL(string : user_chats[indexPath.row].chat_partner!.profile_pic!)
downloadImage(profile_pic_URL!, imageView: cell.chatProfilePic)
cell.chatProfilePic.layer.cornerRadius = 26.5
cell.chatProfilePic.layer.masksToBounds = true

    let dividerLineView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
        return view
    }()
    dividerLineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    cell.addSubview(dividerLineView)
    cell.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-1-[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": dividerLineView]))
    cell.addSubview(dividerLineView)
    cell.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[v0(1)]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": dividerLineView]))
    return cell

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showChat", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "showChat") {

        let IndexPaths = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
        let IndexPath = IndexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! SingleChatFull

        vc.title = user_chats[IndexPath.row].chat_partner!.name
    }

}
```

DATA FETCH :

```
func getUserChats() {
    let scriptUrl = "*****"
    let userID = self.defaults.stringForKey("userId")
    let params = "user_id=" + userID!
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: scriptUrl);
    let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let data = params.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    request.timeoutInterval = 10
    request.HTTPBody=data
    request.HTTPShouldHandleCookies=false
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        do {
            if (data != nil) {
                do {
                    var dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    var delimiter = "]"
                    var token = dataString!.componentsSeparatedByString(delimiter)
                    dataString = token[0] + "]"
                    print(dataString)
                    let data_fixed = dataString!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    do {
                        let jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data_fixed!, options:[])


                        // LOOP THROUGH JSON ARRAY AND FETCH VALUES
                        for anItem in jsonArray as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                            let curr_chat = Chat()
                            if let chatId = anItem["chatId"] as? String {
                                curr_chat.id = chatId
                            }
                            let friend = Friend()
                            let user1id = anItem["user1_id"] as! String
                            let user2id = anItem["user2_id"] as! String
                            if (user1id == userID) {
                                if let user2id = anItem["user2_id"] as? String {
                                    friend.id = user2id
                                }
                                if let user2name = anItem["user2_name"] as? String {
                                    friend.name = user2name
                                }
                                if let user2profilepic = anItem["user2_profile_pic"] as? String {
                                    friend.profile_pic = user2profilepic
                                }
                            }
                            else if (user2id == userID){
                                if let user1id = anItem["user1_id"] as? String {
                                    friend.id = user1id
                                }
                                if let user1name = anItem["user1_name"] as? String {
                                    friend.name = user1name
                                }
                                if let user1profilepic = anItem["user1_profile_pic"] as? String {
                                    friend.profile_pic = user1profilepic
                                }
                            }

                            curr_chat.chat_partner = friend

                            var chat_messages = [Message]()
                            if let dataArray = anItem["message"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                                for (_, messageDictionary) in dataArray {
                                    if let onemessage = messageDictionary as? [String : AnyObject] {                                        let curr_message = Message()
                                        if let messageid = onemessage["message_id"] as? String {
                                            curr_message.id =  messageid
                                        }
                                        if let messagedate = onemessage["timestamp"] as? String {
                                            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                                            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                                            let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(messagedate)
                                            curr_message.date = date
                                        }
                                        if let messagesender = onemessage["sender"] as? String {

                                            curr_message.sender = messagesender
                                        }
                                        if let messagetext = onemessage["text"] as? String {
                                            curr_message.text = messagetext
                                        }
                                        chat_messages.append(curr_message)
                                    }}
                            }

                            curr_chat.chat_messages = chat_messages
                            user_chats.append(curr_chat)
                        }

                    }
                    catch {
                        print("Error: \(error)")
                    }
                }
//                       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(user_chats, forKey: "userChats")

            }
            else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    let uiAlert = UIAlertController(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Please check your internet connection.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                    uiAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { action in
                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
                    }))
                    self.presentViewController(uiAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
            }

        } catch _ {
            NSLog("error")
        }

    })
}
```

The problem is that the collection view is always empty now. I have done some debugging and put a breakpoint inside the first function, and I saw that this method is called when the Loading Screen is still displayed to the user and the chat screen hasn't even been loaded. My suspicion is that this is called before the data is fetched from the internet in the Loading Screen, and as a result the size of the `user_chats` array is 0.  I am used to working with Android and `ListView` where the `ListView` are never populated until the parent view is displayed on screen, hence why I am confused. **The method which fetches the data from the online database works fine as I have already extensively debugged it, so the problem isn't there.**

Comment: Could you also add the code for the function which loads your `datasource`? (How are `user_chats` retrieved?)

Comment: @kye Updated the question, but I don't think this method is the problem as when I tested it it works fine

Comment: as @Richmond Watkins stated below, its an `async` issue. You're most likely reloading your `collectionView` before the data from your `getUserCharts` is returned. See the answer below for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is to add a `completionHandler` to your function to be notified when the data is return and/or when the `async` function is finished executing. The code below is a truncated version of your `getUserCharts` function with a `completionHandler`, which returns a true or false when the data is load (You could modify this to return anything you wish). You can read more about closures/ completion handlers https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html or google.

**function**

```
func getUserChats(completionHandler: (loaded: Bool, dataNil: Bool) -> ()) -> (){
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            do {
                if (data != nil) {
                    do {
                        var dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                        var delimiter = "]"
                        var token = dataString!.componentsSeparatedByString(delimiter)
                        dataString = token[0] + "]"
                        print(dataString)
                        let data_fixed = dataString!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                        do {
                            let jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data_fixed!, options:[])

                            // LOOP THROUGH JSON ARRAY AND FETCH VALUES
                            completionHandler(loaded: true, dataNil: false)
                        }
                        catch {
                            print("Error: \(error)")
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    //Handle error or whatever you wish
                    completionHandler(loaded: true, dataNil: true)
                }

            } catch _ {
                NSLog("error")
            }
```

**How to use it**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        getUserChats(){
            status in
            if status.loaded == true && status.dataNil == false{
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, just one edit I had to make is to add `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
}` otherwise it took ages to load

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is an async issue. I'm not sure how your project is setup but you need to call reloadData() on your collection view when the response is returned.

Comment: When should I call it exactly? The data is fetched within the loading screen which has its own viewController and swift file which doesn't have access to the collectionView

Comment: Many ways to do it. Just depends on your setup. Simplest would be to fire off an NSNotification when you get the response. Then could listen for that notification and reload when it is triggered

Comment: Could you please provide a short code snippet on how to do it in the answer, it would help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

After you have received the data back from the server, and updated the data source for the collection view you need to refresh the collection view (Make sure you are on the main thread, since it is modifying the UI):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Edit:

Also, I'm not completely sure how you have your project setup, but you could create a delegate for your data fetch, so every time you get something back from the server it calls a delegate method that there are new messages. Your collection view controller would subscribe to that delegate, and every time the that method is called it would reload your collection view.

The Delegate:

```
protocol ChatsDelegate {
   func didUpdateChats(chatsArray: NSArray)
}
```

In your Data Fetch:

```
user_chats.append(cur_chat)
self.delegate.didUpdateChats(user_chats)
```

In your collectionView controller:

```
class viewController: ChatsDelegate, ... {
...
   func didUpdateChats(chatsArray: NSArray) {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
         self.collectionView.reloadData()
      }
   }
```

Comment: Yes but the collectionView and the method which fetches the data are not in the same ViewController. The data is fetched in the loading screen, hence I can't call `self.collectionView` because it isn't in the loading screen